# Hide excel columns doesn't work in outlook vba

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I simply can't find a way to hide specific columns in outlook vba. I tried everything. My current code is the following:

```
Sub ExportToExcel()
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim xlWB As Object
    Dim xlSheet As Object
    Dim enviro As String
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim ns As NameSpace
    Dim item As Object
    Dim inbox As MAPIFolder
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    ' Get Excel set up
enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))
'the path of the workbook
 strPath = enviro & "\Documents\test.xlsx"
     On Error Resume Next
     Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
     If Err <> 0 Then
         Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened ... "
         Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
         bXStarted = True
     End If
     On Error GoTo 0
     'Open the workbook to input the data
     Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
     Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")
    ' Process the message record
    `On Error Resume Next
    For j = 2 To 367
        If xlSheet.cells(1, j).Value <> Date And xlSheet.cells(1, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 4 Then
            xlSheet.Columns(j).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        End If
        If xlSheet.cells(1, j).Value = Date Then
            xlSheet.Columns(j).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
            For i = 2 To j - 1
                xlSheet.Columns(i).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                Debug.Print xlSheet.cells(1, i).Value
            Next i
        Exit For
        End If
    Next j
     xlWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A:NB").EntireColumn.AutoFit
     xlWB.Close 1
     If bXStarted Then
         xlApp.Quit
     End If
End Sub
```

The 1st row, starting from the 2nd column of my excel sheet is populated with dates starting from 01.01.2017 and up to 31.12.2017.

I want the macro to hide all dates from before the current day.
As you can see, the debug.print in the test for hiding works as intended and prints all dates from 01.01.2017 to current date-1.

As a side note, xlSheet.Columns(i).Color = 5287936 did not work either.

By placing the On Error Resume Next from before the for in comments, I get an "Application-defined or object-defined error" error.

If I remove all the error tests, I get an "ActiveX component can't create object" error.

New finding, if I `debug.print xlsheet.columns(i).hidden` I get a "true" message in the immediate window. Apparently the code does exactly what it's supposed to, but it just doesn't take effect.

Comment: **Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions.** Do not post code in comments. When someone asks you for code or clarification, you need to [edit] it into your question. The previous conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151709/discussion-on-question-by-nalexp-hide-excel-columns-doesnt-work-in-outlook-vba).

Comment: Which office are you running ?

Comment: I use office 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Autofit manually. You should find it unhides hidden columns.

Move Autofit so it is before the columns are hidden or be more precise about the columns to autofit.

```
Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")

xlWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A:NB").EntireColumn.AutoFit

' Process the message record
For j = 2 To 367
    If xlSheet.Cells(1, j).Value <> Date And xlSheet.Cells(1, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 4 Then
        xlSheet.Columns(j).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    End If

    If xlSheet.Cells(1, j).Value <> Date And xlSheet.Cells(1, j).Interior.ColorIndex <> 0 Then
        xlSheet.Columns(j).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    End If

    If xlSheet.Cells(1, j).Value = Date Then
        xlSheet.Columns(j).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        For i = 2 To j - 1
            xlSheet.Columns(i).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Debug.Print xlSheet.Cells(1, i).Value
        Next i
        Exit For
    End If

Next j
```